# PHP best practice when redirecting unauthenticated users

Tags: php, session, redirect

Okay, so I've seen a couple of different approaches for redirecting a user when, for example, they are not logged in, or are not allowed to view a page, and decide to redirect.

I'll set the scene ... Let's say, when a user has provided a correct username and password, the session variable `$_SESSION['loggedin']` is created. Now, when this user goes to `logged_in_users_only.php`, he can happily see the page. But, along comes Danger Jim, who hasn't logged in, and goes to `logged_in_users_only.php` and get's redirected back to the home page (Maybe with a warning)

So. here's the 2 main approaches I have seen, and was wondering if either of them have security implications, or could somehow allow Danger Jim to see the `logged_in_users_only.php` page

**Example 1**

```
if(session_status()==PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    //show content
} else {
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
if(session_status()==PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit;
}
//show content
```

Personally, I have always gone with the first approach. I think it's because the code seems to sit nicely 'trapped' within the brackets (Maybe I just like looking at it that way Lol).

But I am intrigued to know if example 2 could **never** let Danger Jim see the content.

Comment: Well I would check if the session value is the same as some sort of user id, but I don't think there are big differences between the two.

Comment: Yeah I do the user id thing, I've just not included that in this example :D ... Do you have a preference as to which one to use, or do you just use 'as needed'?

Comment: Good question! Using `exit();` is in general bad practice and most code analyzer tools will warn about this.

Comment: Surley Example 2 makes the `//show content` code easier to See and Read as it is not wrapped inside an IF. Other than that they are basically the same.

Comment: @Stretch I use the bottom one but that is just my preference. And as Sliq sead, you don't need the `exit;` after a header. Also as RiggsFolly just sead, some IDE's don't support code coloring if everything is inside an echo function like in the first example.

Comment: **WARNING!** @Goudgeld1 I don't said that :) The exit is VERY important, but it's also not perfect coding style. The header() function is only useful for browsers (!), non-browser tools parsing your application will be able to override the browser redirect and therefore do bad things to your application (= try to cURL the page, it will go on without accepting the header() redirect).

Comment: @Sliq O... misread that. I didn't think it was important but after reading the [header manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) you are right :P. Even after all those years there are always things to learn!

Comment: Thanks all for the comments ... My stomach did do a little turn when someone said not to use the `exit()` lol, but thankfully @Goudgeld1 cleared that one up Lol ... I use Notepad++ as my 'IDE' (If you can call it that) so code coloring isn't a problem there ... So I think I will continue to use the first example, just out of spite so that I don't have to re-code everything to be standardized :/ ... Even though I do now prefer the second example ... :( ... Maybe one day I'll get to it Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is quite a good question so I will try to give a good answer!

Both examples will work and the biggest difference is that it indeed looks safer in the first example. But both do the same thing.
There is just one thing you have to consider, in the first example:

```
if(session_status()==PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    echo "logged in!";
} else {
    header('Location: home.php');
    Exit;
}
```

You have to echo all your content. some IDE's don't support HTML coloring inside of the PHP echo function.

I personaly use the second example becous my IDE doesn't support code coloring inside PHP strings.

```
if(session_status()==PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: home.php');
    Exit;
}
```

After the `header();`, the page is closed so there is no 'real' danger by using the second example.
If you want some more details, you should read the [header manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) if you haven't already.

Good Luck with your code and I hope we at stackoverflow helped you to become a better programmer. They helped me a lot :)

p.s. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Cool thanks for your input into it, and yes, I should really read the header manual again Lol ... I've only skimmed over it before ... As I said in the comments above, I do now prefer the second example, but I think I'll wait til I re-code everything ... I'm in too deep now Lol ...Thanks again